# Intellij IDEA very slow while typing in editor (Scala only)

Tags: performance, scala, intellij-idea

Using IDEA 14.1.5 ultimate edition in Scala project there are a lot of performance problems. After typing a several symbols in the editor I have a lag for a few seconds. This happens only in Scala project (big project), in Java project everything is fine.

Core i7 4770, 16Gb RAM, projects located on SDD disk

vm.option have the following settings

```
-Xms750m
-Xmx8192m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=225m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-server
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

It's very terrible. I try to turn off all inspections, autocompletion and version control (!!!), but it doesn't help. I'm thinking of starting working in notepad.

Can anyone help me? What else should I turn off to increase perfomance?

upd:
I found that turning off junit plugin give me some performance, but i have a  "little" problem - gradle plugin require junit. 
I'm using a last version of all plugins and I can't update to version 15, because I have a licence for version 14.

I can't understand how and why any plugin can leads to performance degradation for editor(!). Why I can't turn off all edit handlers? This IDE designed for text edit?  I really  feel performance problem, and this give me lot of pain in this case.

Comment: Try reporting it as a bug: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827577-Reporting-performance-problems ... also I would recommend trying out IntelliJ 15 if your licence permits it, after all it is next major release and this is something that might already be fixed there

Answer (score 2):

I usually disable type-aware highlighting and set the inspection level to syntax only. That helps a lot, especially in case of string interpolations and Spray.io routes with complex implicit marshallers.

```
java/idea/bin/idea64.vmoptions

 -Xms256m
 -Xmx1024m
 -XX:MaxPermSize=350m
 -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=225m
 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
 -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
 -ea
 -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
 -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
 -Dhidpi=true
```

Comment: This was aleady done, I turn inspection in power-down mode and disable policy

Comment: I used to have some performance problems while working with Lift mapper, but they had fixed it some time ago. Perhaps you could file an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues and somebody will come to help.

Comment: Oh yes, also make sure you're using the latest Scala plugin